# Google Sheet App Script - cannot select the last cell correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Google App Script to do some repetitive tasks for me, like copying some data. Because the data size vary from time to time and I don't want to copy the header. So I try this to get my data range:

```js
spreadsheet.getRange(2, 1, spreadsheet.getLastRow(), spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('D2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

However, when I run it in my Macro, the error occurs.

**Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.**

Should I use another way to get my data? Or I just need to revise this line of codes?

Answer (score 0):

Before utilizing the Google Sheets API service, try to enable it. See this [`Enable and disable APIs`](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your variable was declared like this:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

This variable is referring to the whole Spreadsheet, you still need to refer to the sheet that you're going to modify using .getSheets()[0] or .getActiveSheet(), you can modify your code like this:

```
spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, spreadsheet.getLastRow(), spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('D2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

Or:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, spreadsheet.getLastRow(), spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('D2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

Reference:

- [Use example for .getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)